# Converting a pandas dataframe to a csv choosing only certain columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a pandas dataframe to a csv choosing only certain columns. However, after the new pandas update, I get this error :

```
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported
```

Here is my code  :

```
    #split into the correct columns
    split_data = df["Date,Country,City,Specie,count,min,max,median,variance"].str.split(",")
    data = split_data.to_list()
    names = ['Date', 'Country', 'City', 'Specie', 'count', 'min', 'max', 'median', 'variance']
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=names)


    new_df.drop(['City', 'count', 'min', 'max', 'variance'], axis = 1)

   #calculating the mean
    mean_data = new_df.groupby(['Date', 'Country', 'Specie']).mean()


    clean_data = mean_data[(mean_data.T != 0).any()]

    bycountry_data = clean_data.groupby(['Date', 'Country', 'Specie']).mean()

    names = ['Date', 'Country', 'Specie', 'median']
    #convert to csv
    bycountry_data.to_csv('bycountry.csv',index=False, sep=";",columns = names)
```

Here are the first lines of the dataframe i want to convert to a csv :

```
Date       Country Specie    median    
2014-12-29 AT      co        0.10
                   no2      15.78
                   pm10     20.80
                   pm25     69.50
                   so2       2.00
```

(Please do not hesitate if you have any idea as to how I could improve my code appart from this error, as I am new to Python.)

Comment: `new_df.drop(['City', 'count', 'min', 'max', 'variance'], axis = 1)` doesn't do anything because you didn't set `inplace=True`

Comment: It looks like `['Date', 'Country', 'Specie']` are in your **`Index`** because of the `groupby`. This means that when you specify them in the `columns=` argument they won't be found, hence the error telling you you're passing a list that contains columns your DataFrame doesn't have. You can `.reset_index()` before writing the DataFrame, or use `index=True` and only specify `columns=['median']`

Comment: @roganjosh - thank you. What does inplace do please ? I checked on the documentation but I don't get why I need it

Comment: @ALollz Very clear explanation. It worked, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
#split into the correct columns
split_data = df["Date,Country,City,Specie,count,min,max,median,variance"].str.split(",")
data = split_data.to_list()
names = ['Date', 'Country', 'City', 'Specie', 'count', 'min', 'max', 'median', 'variance']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=names)


new_df = new_df.drop(['City', 'count', 'min', 'max', 'variance'], axis = 1)



#calculating the mean
mean_data = new_df.groupby(['Date', 'Country', 'Specie']).mean()

clean_data = mean_data[(mean_data.T != 0).any()]

bycountry_data = clean_data.groupby(['Date', 'Country', 'Specie']).mean()

names = ['Date', 'Country', 'Specie', 'median']
#convert to csv
bycountry_data.to_csv('bycountry.csv',index=False, sep=";",columns = names)
```